# How to extract element values from xml file using nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

From the below xml file, which has more than 1 'SellerAccount' elements, I need to extract & store all 'ServiceCode' values for 'SellerAccount' = 98765432.Can someone please suggest/guide me with this?

```
    <SellerRequest>
    <Header>
            <ExtractDateTime>2014-09-11T12:04:50</ExtractDateTime>
            <SequenceNumber>1001</SequenceNumber>
            <RecordCount>32</RecordCount>
        </Header>
        <Requests>
    <Request type="Install">
        <ActionCode>101</ActionCode>
            <SellerID>10</SellerID>
            <SellerAccount>123456</SellerAccount>
            <Salutation>Mr</Salutation>
            <FirstName>Matt</FirstName>
            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
            <HomePhoneNumber>91234568</HomePhoneNumber>
            <WorkPhoneNumber></WorkPhoneNumber>
            <MobileNumber>21123456</MobileNumber>
            <Email>xml_file@example.test</Email>
            <StreetNumber>3</StreetNumber>
            <UnitFlatNumber></UnitFlatNumber>
            <StreetNumberSuffix></StreetNumberSuffix>
            <StreetName>Testing DRIVE</StreetName>
            <Suburb>SUBURB</Suburb>
            <City>CITY</City>
            <PostCode>12345</PostCode>
            <SellerUserID>seller</SellerUserID>
            <SellerOrderNumber></SellerOrderNumber>
            <Comment></Comment>

        <NominatedPINNumber>1234</NominatedPINNumber>
        <NextOfKinName>contact</NextOfKinName>
                <NextOfKinAddressLine1>1 testing Drive</NextOfKinAddressLine1>
                <NextOfKinAddressLine2>City</NextOfKinAddressLine2>
                <NextOfKinPhoneNumber>091234567</NextOfKinPhoneNumber>
                <DateOfBirth>1980-01-01</DateOfBirth>
        <NameChangeRequest>N</NameChangeRequest>
        <BillingAddressLine1>3    TESTING DRIVE</BillingAddressLine1>
                <BillingAddressLine2>SUBURB</BillingAddressLine2>
                <BillingAddressLine3>CITY 12345</BillingAddressLine3>
        <PreferredDate>2014-09-12</PreferredDate>
                <PreferredTimeSlot>20</PreferredTimeSlot>
        <BillCycle>1</BillCycle>
<Occurrences>
<Occurrence ID="1">
<ServiceCode>001</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>002</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>003</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>004</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>005</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>006</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>007</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>008</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>009</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>010</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>011</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>012</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>013</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>014</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>015</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>016</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>017</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>018</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>019</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>020</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>021</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>AB123</ServiceCode>
</Occurrence>
<Occurrence ID="2">
<ServiceCode>001</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>002</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>003</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>004</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>005</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>006</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>007</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>008</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>009</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>010</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>011</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>012</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>013</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>014</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>015</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>016</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>017</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>018</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>AB123</ServiceCode>
</Occurrence>
</Occurrences>

</Request>
<Request type="Install">
        <ActionCode>101</ActionCode>
            <SellerID>10</SellerID>
            <SellerAccount>98765432</SellerAccount>
            <Salutation>Mr</Salutation>
            <FirstName>James</FirstName>
            <LastName>Tester</LastName>
            <HomePhoneNumber>91234567</HomePhoneNumber>
            <WorkPhoneNumber>91234568</WorkPhoneNumber>
            <MobileNumber>21123456</MobileNumber>
            <Email>example@email.test</Email>
            <StreetNumber>3</StreetNumber>
            <UnitFlatNumber></UnitFlatNumber>
            <StreetNumberSuffix></StreetNumberSuffix>
            <StreetName>TESTING DRIVE</StreetName>
            <Suburb>SUBURB</Suburb>
            <City>CITY</City>
            <PostCode>12345</PostCode>
            <SellerUserID>seller_2</SellerUserID>
            <SellerOrderNumber></SellerOrderNumber>
            <Comment>new customer</Comment>

        <NominatedPINNumber>3456</NominatedPINNumber>
        <NextOfKinName>contact</NextOfKinName>
                <NextOfKinAddressLine1>1 testing DRIVE</NextOfKinAddressLine1>
                <NextOfKinAddressLine2>City</NextOfKinAddressLine2>
                <NextOfKinPhoneNumber>099876543</NextOfKinPhoneNumber>
                <DateOfBirth>1980-01-01</DateOfBirth>
        <NameChangeRequest>N</NameChangeRequest>
        <BillingAddressLine1>3 TESTING DRIVE</BillingAddressLine1>
                <BillingAddressLine2>SUBURB</BillingAddressLine2>
                <BillingAddressLine3>CITY 12345</BillingAddressLine3>
        <PreferredDate>2014-09-12</PreferredDate>
                <PreferredTimeSlot>20</PreferredTimeSlot>
        <BillCycle>1</BillCycle>
<Occurrences>
<Occurrence ID="1">
<ServiceCode>001</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>002</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>003</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>004</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>005</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>006</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>007</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>008</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>009</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>010</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>011</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>012</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>013</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>014</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>015</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>016</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>017</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>018</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>019</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>020</ServiceCode>
<ServiceCode>AB123</ServiceCode>
</Occurrence>
</Occurrences>

</Request>
    </Requests>
</SellerRequest>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have parsed the XML:

```
doc = Nokogiri.XML(xml)
```

you can use XPath to get what you want:

```
codes = doc.xpath("//Request[SellerAccount='98765432']//ServiceCode").map(&:text)
```

The `text` method simply extracts the strings from the Nokogiri objects.

Output:

```
["001",
 "002",
 "003",
 "004",
 "005",
 "006",
 "007",
 "008",
 "009",
 "010",
 "011",
 "012",
 "013",
 "014",
 "015",
 "016",
 "017",
 "018",
 "019",
 "020",
 "AB123"]
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. getting started with Nokogiri. I was trying something like this:f = File.open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Request.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
doc.xpath("//SellerAccount[text()='98765432']").first.parent.xpath(".//Occurrence").each_with_index{|occ, index| 
  codes["occ_#{index}"] = []
  occ.xpath(".//ServiceCode").each{|serv| 
  codes["occ_#{index}"] << serv.text
  }
 }

Comment: Thanks. I recommend editing your question and adding the code you tried to it. It is encouraged on SO to do so. As you can see, questions tend to get downvoted if you haven't shown an attempt to solve the problem.